# Correct Implementation of Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I've been thinking about this for a few days now, and I am under the belief that my thinking of how multithreading works is flawed. I've consulted the API for Concurrency, and still did not get an answer to my question.

If I have some process that I want to return a unique string, and I want 100 different threads to run this process (thereby giving me 100 threads with 100 different strings), I can utilize executorServices to accomplish this, correct?

Then, once every thread has a string, I want to send that string to a queue, thereby blasting the queue with messages (again, sounds like a usage for a executorService.submit() call).

Lastly, Once a thread sends the message to to the queue, I want this thread to immediately start checking another queue for a response (matching it's unique string), and if it matches, output some data and terminte.

Although I am under the impression that using Executorservice would be the answer to my issue, I am failing in implementation. Is there another solution that I am missing, or does multithreading using using this method suffice--and if so, how?

Code thus far. I stopped after the sendTextMessage after realizing my issue:

```
int arraySize = 750; //Number of hits to send out: MANIPULATE THIS IF YOU WANT TO SEND MORE


//  String[] toSend = new String[arraySize];
    String[] rfids = new String[arraySize];
    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    //Insert Connection information and set up clients here//

    clientSend.connectSend();
    clientRec.connectRec(); //edit to ensure credientials are corrects
//  System.out.println("Signed-in");
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer(); //What holds out output
    File infile = new File("infile.txt"); //Populating Rfids array

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(infile);
    for (int i = 0; i <= arraySize-1; i++) 
    {

        if(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            rfids[i]=scan.nextLine();
//          System.out.println(rfids[i]);
        }
    }
    scan.close();
    count=0;
ExecutorService load = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(arraySize);

        Callable<String> readAndSendPrep = () ->
        {
            StringBuffer fileBasedResponse = new StringBuffer();

            String rfid = "";
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")); //This is the standard message that will be sent everytime, give or take
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }    
            String line; //temp var
            for(int x = 0; x<arraySize-1;x++)
            {
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) 
                    {


                        if (line.trim().startsWith("<MessageId>")) 
                        {
                        //  System.out.println(rf);
                            rfid = rfids[arraySize]; //not necessary i think
                            int endIndex = line.trim().indexOf("</MessageId>");
                            String messageId = line.trim().substring(11, endIndex);
                            line =  "<MessageId>" + messageId + " - " + rfids[arraySize] + "</MessageId>"; //puts unique ID in thread details

                        } 
                        else if (line.trim().startsWith("str")) 
                        {
                        //  System.out.println(allRFID[thisIndex]);
                            rfid = rfids[arraySize];
                            line = "str" + rfids[arraySize] + "str"; //Another unique ID
                        //  System.out.println("BOOM");
                        }
                        fileBasedResponse.append(line); //put the whole response to the StringBuffer object

    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);
            return fileBasedResponse.toString();
        };
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        Future<String> fileBasedResponse = load.submit(readAndSendPrep);
        while(!fileBasedResponse.isDone())
        {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }

        String fileBasedResponseStr = fileBasedResponse.toString();
        Runnable sender = () ->
        {
            try {
                clientSend.sendTextMessage(fileBasedResponseStr);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        clientSend.close(); //close connections
        clientRec.close();
        System.out.println(output.toString()); //output the results
        System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: You should post some code up, minimum verifiable example

Comment: @ThomasCook I see, edited to add code.

Comment: Have a look at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService, it might be of help to you. Also, task is different from thread. you can have 700 tasks but only 10 threads to complete them.

Comment: Use `ThreadPoolExecutor`, you'll get most of the thing out of the box.